# jquery $.each gives me an object that does not have hasClass method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to iterate over a collection of items with the class `required`. I think I must be using the `$.each` function incorrectly.

```
function required(address) {
    //object to hold elements not passing validation tests
    var pass = true;
    $('.required').each(function(index, elem){
        console.log(elem);
        //check if it has the class indicating it is an email
        if (elem.hasClass('re')) {
            var validEmail = validateEmail(address.email);
            if (!validEmail){
                $(this).addClass('nv'); 
            }

        }
      });
  }
```

I see that the element in the console is 
`<input type=​"text" id=​"name_input" class=​"pr required">​`

And then the error
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'hasClass'`

How can that object not have the hasClass method?

Comment: shouldnt it be $(elem).hasClass('..')?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first hint should be that the object is an `#<HTMLInputElement>` and not a jQuery object. Use `$(elem).hasClass('re');`

Comment: aha yes. That is quite an obvious hint now that i see it. why wouldn't jquery not return a jquery object? Thanks much!

Comment: Because you are iterating over DOM elements, so it will return a DOM element. You will need to create a jQuery object from that DOM element :)

Answer (score 2):

`elem` in your code is a DOM Element object, if you want to use jQuery methods you should create a jQuery object first:

```
if ($(elem).hasClass('re')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You make the class .re part of your jQuery selector and save the if/then:

```
function required(address)
{
    //object to hold elements not passing validation tests
    var pass = true;
    $('.required.re').each(function(index, elem) {
        console.log(elem);
        var validEmail = validateEmail(address.email);
        if (!validEmail){
            $(this).addClass('nv'); 
        }
    });
}
```